# helm chart download failed using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am facing one issue.

I am trying to install ALB controller using terraform and it failed got error like failed to download chart.

below is error I got ,
[image: error]

Below is my Terraform code which I am working on,

```
resource "helm_release" "lb" {
  name       = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  repository = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"
  chart      = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  set {
    name  = "region"
    value = var.region
  }
  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = "2.4.2"
  }
  set {
    name  = "image.repository"
    value = "602401143452.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/amazon/aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }
  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.create"
    value = "true"
  }
  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.name"
    value = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }
  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = data.aws_eks_cluster.mycluster.name
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using IAM roles for ServiceAccounts?

Comment: yes as of now have given administrator access..

Comment: Ok, so the [documentation for the chart] (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/aws/aws-load-balancer-controller#tl-dr) says the following: `helm install aws-load-balancer-controller eks/aws-load-balancer-controller --set clusterName=my-cluster -n kube-system --set serviceAccount.create=false --set serviceAccount.name=aws-load-balancer-controller`.  So it seems now you are using `serviceAccount.create= true` and that might need to be `serviceAccount.create=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `verify=false` and re-run terraform?

```
resource "helm_release" "lb" {
   ...
   verify = false
   ...
}
```

Comment: NO luck. same issue unable to download.